# Java connection to mySQL understanding

Tags: java, mysql

Sorry again for knocking here again but I want to ask a final question. I found this code and it was not commented on. Can someone please comment it for me so that I can understand what the code is trying to do. Learning connection on my own. :(

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Connection conn = null;

        try {  
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/CLASS","root","sirikali1");
          Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement();
          String selectStuff = "select b.yearID, b.playerID from Student;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I hope you will understand this one, I fathom when one learns alone everything sounds so difficult while it is not.

I hope this helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 Connection conn = null;

   try {


// The driver allows you to query the database with Java
        // forName dynamically loads the class for you


   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // DriverManager is used to handle a set of JDBC drivers
            // getConnection establishes a connection to the database
            // You must also pass the userid and password for the database
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(" path where your database is, plus put your username and password");

            // Statement objects executes a SQL query
            // createStatement returns a Statement object
 Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement();

            // This is the query I'm sending to the database

           String selectStuff = "select b.yearID, b.playerID from Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain some stuff to you the best I can...

```
    try {  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lahman591","root","sirikali1")
```

The above line is known as a try with resources, implemented in java 7 as a way to close any documented closeable resource used. The Class.forName really just points to the needed driver used for mySQL you can read about it here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing.html

Otherwise it will start a connection by (URL, user, password).

```
          Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement();
```

Here you created an instance of a statement which doesn't do anything it needs to be called to get a result...

```
        String selectStuff = "select b.yearID, b.playerID from Student;
```

So if you know mySQL you know what you are selecting here, if you don't know mySQL look up the commands before proceeding.

Normally you would want a response from the statement... if you do then a normal way to do it is

```
 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectstuff);
```

Now there's your result you can parse it look up some methods in the javadocs I think i have said enough